# can WSO2 BAM work only with Oracle DB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I'm able to configure WSO2 BAM data source WSO2_CARBON_DB to work with Oracle DB, but I'm not able to do the same with other data sources.

Is it possible to disable Cassandra and make WSO2 BAM works only with Oracle DB, including all stored data (configuration / input data / analyzed data and so on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the stat store, we use cassandra. It gives high read/write performance than RDBMS. You can not configure RDBMS instead of Cassandra.

For other DB related operations you can use any RDBMS( mssql/mysql..).

Eg: registry/user store

Comment: Thanks Ratha, i wanted to confirm this.